# Dynamically inserted textbox values to be stored in a variable

Tags: codeigniter

```
<tr style="background: #D0CDCD;">
  <td colspan='2'>
    <input type="text" name="mytext1[]">
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan='2' style="text-align:right;">
    <input type="text" name="mytext2[]" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();">
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my html code to add dynamic textboxes. 
JS Script is follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields= 3;
  var x = 1; 
  $('a').click(function() {
    if(x < max_fields){
      x++;
      $('#myTable #row').append('<tr class="child"><td class="child" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="mytext1[]"></td><td></td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input type="text" name="mytext2[]"></td></tr>');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

My problem is that I need to store the dynamically added textbox values to a variable so that I can perform some mathematical operations in that. I don't know how to achieve this. Please help me.

Comment: There is a reference answer...please check it it may help you out...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345480/query-add-two-input-fields-together

Comment: Sir, number of textboxes depends upon the user. It may b 1 , 2 or 3.. So i need to extract the values that the user has givev.

Comment: but here this text box is append only 3 times @RevathiKrishnaK

Comment: yes, its limited to 3. just for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

I got the result. I make use of **javascript** and **jQuery**

```
<tr style="background: #D0CDCD;">
    <td colspan='2'><input type="text" name="mytext1[]"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan='2' style="text-align:right;">
          <input type="text" class="value_field" name="mytext2[]"  >
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Function to append**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
      $('#myTable #row').append('<tr class="child"><td class="child"           colspan="2"><input type="text" name="mytext1[]"></td><td></td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input type="text" name="mytext2[]" class="value_field"></td></tr>');
      $("input.value_field").blur(function(){
            check_value();
        });
    });
});
$("input.value_field").blur(function(){
     check_value();
});
```